# How to flip an image using a range slider in html5 css3 and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project and I want to rotate an image using a range to rotate the image 180 degrees.

I am having difficulty getting the range slider to operate the flip/ rotation- help needed.
thank you.

I have tried many different variations, using the different technique by different people, but they use a div, I am using an image class instead.
was wondering if it is possible to rotate/flip an image class?

```
'''

https://codepen.io/lukemersh/pen/EJREaJ

'''
```

Actual results don't happen.
I can move the slider, but it doesn't rotate the image, please help.

Comment: Please don't format codepen links that way. Insert the link to codepen, and then include the most relevant portion of code to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your id of the shoe image is wrong, change:

```
document.getElementById('img.shoe')
```

to

```
document.getElementById('shoe')
```

"img.shoe" is a selector for images with class shoe, its not an element identifier. To use such a selector you'd need to use "document.querySelector"

Comment: fantastic. rotation solved. What I really want it to do is when the slider reaches the other end of the slider it simply flips the image 180 degrees- but many thanks for helping sorting it out from what I have.

Comment: Then you can do something like ```value = value >= 180 ? 180 : 0;``` but confused as to why you would need a slider if you are only flipping 180

Comment: I want the user to be able to see ( supposedly) both side of the shoe, I thought that the slider would be a good idea. Ps- where would i place that piece of code? I am not good with JS that is my next module. Many thAanks in advance.

Comment: Place it as the first line in the rotate function. It changes the value variable so it is always zero unless the slider is at the end.

Comment: sorry im stupid!! do you mean in the html or the JS or CSS. I am only just getting my head around this advanced code. many thanks

Comment: In the JS, line 14

Comment: Thank you very much, I have got to JS yet so I dont really understand how it all works. Thats my next module, working on Freecodecamp.org and trying to work through the whole full stack course.

Comment: its not quite flipping it 180 degs.  looks more like 90 degs, it appears upside down. many thanks

Comment: It is rotating 180 degrees, if you want flipping as opposed to rotation it would require you to use a different transform, ```transform: scaleX(-1);```..

Comment: Hi many thanks for that. I have changes the values in the css, but i guess i need to change the rotate to scale in the JS as well?

Comment: Yes, you do need to update the JS as well to dynamically change the transform based on the user input. I'm afraid I can't help you much more now on this problem, stackoverflow is generally for helping with specific issues rather than continuing step by step guidance. Good luck!